# I want to transfer azure bot framework web app bot projects and related app service to another azure account. What are the possible ways to do it?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I want to transfer azure bot framework web app bot project, related app service LUIS apps and qnamaker knowledge base to another azure account. What are the possible ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can only move your web app to **a new resource group**, **a new subscription** and **a new region**.

According to the official document, you should read [Checklist before moving resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription?toc=/azure/app-service/toc.json#checklist-before-moving-resources) and [Move guidance for App Service resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations) first.
[image]

Then follow the steps to move your resources: [Use the Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription?toc=/azure/app-service/toc.json#use-the-portal). Choose **Move to another subscription** option.
[image]